# How to expand VScode directories

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this has been answered somewhere before, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to properly Google this query. I got a new computer and I've mostly setup my Visual Studio Code environment, but I have never liked the shorthand directory structure if defaults to. I want to change my directories to be full dropdowns and not a one-line `somedirectory/subdirectory/subdirectory/something.js`

Apparently there is some fancy word for it but I have no idea what that word is and it's making my searching surprisingly difficult.

So, what setting do I need to change in VScode to make **all** of my directories follow the format that `Collection` has in the example below and not like `lessons/flashcards`?

[image]

Thanks!

**TLDR; I want every directory to be a full dropdown. None of this `lessons/flashcards` nonsense.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achieve this go to your vs code settings and search `Compact Folders`. It will be checked by default. Uncheck that and it will work.

[image]